# Include problems in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, include

I need to turn allow_url_include On. How can I do this? I have access to .htaccess as well as php.ini.

I'm using PHP version 5.2.9

I've tried adding

php_value allow_url_include On

in .htaccess and

allow_url_include = On

in php.ini.

Both files are at the root of my website.

Is there a way to use the curl/get page function as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're grabbing the right php.ini file?

If you're on a linux box, you might be grabbing the wrong one.  I've seen that happen in the past.  If you are indeed using Linux, open the terminal and type

```
which httpd
which php
```

Then you'll know if your pointing to the right locations.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.  After I was burned by that problem a few times - it's been etched into my mind....

Comment: Can you select my response as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to use as a file to include  you will need to enable both url_fopen and url_include.

The relevant php documentation entry is available here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php